# Obtaining sample rate of wav file without loading entire file

Tags: python, audio, wav

I have a `.wav` file on my disk somewhere. Such a file consists (basically) of a sampling rate together with a wave form given as a long sequence of numbers. Typical Python libraries for loading `.wav` files will give both the sampling rate and the data: for example, there is [`scipy.io.wavfile.read`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.io.wavfile.read.html) or [`wavio.read`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wavio).

Because the `.wav` files might be large and loading them might take a long time, and sometimes I might be interested in their sampling rate before wanting to have access to the waveform, I am looking for a fast way to extract the sampling rate from the `.wav` file in Python -- one that does not require reading the entire file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`wave`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/wave.html) package from the standard library:

```
import wave

file = ...
with wave.open(file, 'rb') as f:
    framerate = f.getframerate()
```